# Cron job not sending emails - PHPJabbers script

Tags: php, email, cron, jobs

This is pretty much my last resort as I am about to give up after fighting it for the laast 3 weeks. Just took a stab that someone might be able to help or been in this situation before. I bought the "Appointment Scheduler" script from PHPJabbers and it works great EXCEPT for the e-mailing a reminder 24 hours before the customer's appointment. I originally had this installed on GoDaddy and kept getting an error when the cron would run about Zend Optimizer not being installed (which it was and everything else ran fine) so I installed it on another site I have and I seem to have it working, but no e-mails get sent. Every hour when the cron runs I get this:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Set-Cookie: StivaApp=c29a18b3ff60f13f27c3f557bda0bc25; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

My cron job code (done through my cpanel) is as follows (with my site folder changed to ****):

`php /home/****/public_html/josh/script/cron.php`

and it runs every 30 minutes. I have 4 test appointments in the database that should be getting confirmation emails, but nothing happens.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I could try next?

Comment: Does running `php /home/****/public_html/josh/script/cron.php` manually on shell works?

Comment: Is the problem that the script isn't running, or it's running but the script isn't sending emails?  They're two very different problems.

Comment: Don't know how to do it manually on shell, so I'm not sure (but would try if you can point me to a page that tells me how to do it), and the problem is the cron runs but no e-mails are sent. Thanks for looking guys, I appreciate it.

Comment: If you have shell access, the cron command is the shell command(php /home/****/public_html/josh/script/cron.php). The other way is to browse to the file with your internet browser and it will run the script. You should add some echos/print to the script to maybe find out if it is failing somewhere

Comment: Thanks CJ. I'm afraid I just don't know enough (or anything) about scripting, so I think I just have to write this off as a loss. I'm an html/css guy who bought this application as it was supposed to be nothing more than dropping it on my page and following a few simple instructions and I would be up and running. It's too bad as I'm so close to having it working. I'll still give you credit for answering even though I don't know enough to follow the directions! Thanks again to all.

Comment: No, I believe it is done through sendmail. It sends an email when an appointment is made (and that one works fine). I get the message from the cron job every 30 minutes (that is currently what I have it set for while I'm trying different things) so I'm assuming since I get that cron message that it is running.

Comment: Looks like the support staff at PHPJabbers is getting me fixed up. Not sure what the fix ended up being, but they got it working on my test site...now I just have to duplicate that on my live site. Thanks to everyone who offered help and I'll consider this closed.

Answer (score 1):

Today I worked one of the issues out with my domain host. My cron jobs were running but I was getting no email notice. The answer: "...cron jobs that produce no output will not send an email. As cron won't just discard output generated by a job, If a cron job generates output that is otherwise not handled (eg, by mailing it to someone, or putting it into a file or redirecting it to /dev/null) this output will be emailed as described in the MAILTO variable."

My cron job was truncating mysql tables and generating no output, hence no email notification.